# Create array of hashs from array and variables in while loop

Tags: arrays, ruby, hash, while-loop

From an array like this:

```
@upc = ['123ab', '456cd']
```

and a set of variables that are determined in a `while` loop, which, during the first iteration, will look like this:

```
@vendor = "Nike"
@type = "Running"
@color = "Blue"
```

and during the second iteration, may look like this:

```
@vendor = "Converse"
@type = "Hi-Top"
@color = "Red"
```

I want to get this:

```
[
  {:upc=>"123ab", :vendor=>"Nike", :type=>"Running", :color=>"Blue"},
  {:upc=>"456cd", :vendor=>"Converse", :type=>"Hi-Top", :color=>"Red"}
]
```

I'm using this code:

```
final_hash =
@upc.map{|upc| {:upc=> upc, :vendor => @vendor, :type => @type, :color => @color}}
```

but I end up getting the variables put in once and then duplicated like this:

```
[
  {:upc=>"123ab", :vendor=>"Nike", :type=>"Running", :color=>"Blue"},
  {:upc=>"456cd", :vendor=>"Nike", :type=>"Running", :color=>"Blue"}
]
```

How can I get the array and variables into an array of hashes?

Answer (score 0):

```
final_hash = @upc.map{|upc| {:upc=> upc, :vendor => @vendor, :type => @type, :color => @color}}
```

This won't work because it will only use the last value for `@vendor`, `@type` and `@color`.

When you have code like:

```
@vendor = "Nike"
@type = "Running"
@color = "Blue"

@vendor = "Converse"
```

The first value of `@vendor` is overwritten by the last one.

You may want to store your data in an array:

```
@shoe_1 = { vendor: "Nike", type: "Running", color: "Blue" }
@shoe_2 = ...
@shoes = [@shoe_1, @shoe_2]
```

Now you can merge the arrays:

```
@shoes.map.with_index{| shoe, i | shoe.merge upc:@upc[ i ]}
=> [{
    :vendor => "Nike",
      :type => "Running",
     :color => "Blue",
       :upc => "123ab"
   },...
```

Comment: I like this solution, I just have another question now! I'm having trouble creating the hashes on the fly. I have an array of those upc's, so I know how many hashes I need:
   long = upc.length and then maybe long.times do |x|
but then not so sure?? @Cary Swoveland

Answer (score 0):

As @BSeven suggests, you probably should use a different data structure, one that suits the way in which you wish to use the information. For example, one possibility might be:

```
h = { "Nike"     => { "Running" => { "Blue"=>"123ab", "Black"=>"123ac" },
                      "Walking" => { "Pink"=>"124ab", "Mauve"=>"124af" } },
      "Converse" => { "Hi-Top"  => { "Red" =>"456cd", "Green"=>"457cg"  },
                      "Running" => { "Red" =>"457cd", "Black"=>"457ch" } } }
```

This would allow you to easily answer the following sorts of questions:

**What colors do Nike running shoes come in, and what is the upc code of each?**

```
h["Nike"]["Running"] 
  #=> {"Blue"=>"123ab", "Black"=>"123ac"}
```

**Which manufacturers produce black running shows?**

```
h.select { |_, types|
  types.key?("Running") && types["Running"].key?("Black") }.keys
  #=> ["Nike", "Converse"]
```

**What are the manufactures, types and upc codes of all the black shoes?**

```
h.each_with_object([]) do |(mfg, types), ans|
  types.each do |type, colors|
    ans << { mfg: mfg, type: type, upc: colors["Black"] } if colors.key?("Black")
  end
end
  #=> [{:mfg=>"Nike",     :type=>"Running", :upc=>"123ac"},
  #    {:mfg=>"Converse", :type=>"Running", :upc=>"457ch"}]
```

**Which shoe has upc "456cd"?**

```
upc = h.each_with_object({}) do |(mfg, types), g|
  types.each do |type, colors|
     colors.each { |color, upc| g[upc] = [mfg: mfg, type: type, color: color] }
  end
end
  #=> {"123ab"=>[{:mfg=>"Nike",     :type=>"Running", :color=>"Blue" }],
  #    "123ac"=>[{:mfg=>"Nike",     :type=>"Running", :color=>"Black"}],
  #    "124ab"=>[{:mfg=>"Nike",     :type=>"Walking", :color=>"Pink" }],
  #    "124af"=>[{:mfg=>"Nike",     :type=>"Walking", :color=>"Mauve"}],
  #    "456cd"=>[{:mfg=>"Converse", :type=>"Hi-Top",  :color=>"Red"  }],
  #    "457cg"=>[{:mfg=>"Converse", :type=>"Hi-Top",  :color=>"Green"}],
  #    "457cd"=>[{:mfg=>"Converse", :type=>"Running", :color=>"Red " }],
  #    "457ch"=>[{:mfg=>"Converse", :type=>"Running", :color=>"Black"}]} 
upc["456cd"]
  #=> [{:mfg=>"Converse", :type=>"Hi-Top", :color=>"Red"}]
```

This is only tangentially related to your question, but I thought you might find it useful.

Comment: Yes, this really begs the question, "Where is this data coming from? What format is it in?"

Comment: So all this data is just going into a csv file to be uploaded.. its coming from an API that I parse, put into variables in a while loop, and then place into a hash where I can then put into the final csv.. if that helps??

Answer (score 0):

Your `while`-loop has to control the iteration over the upc elements.

```
final_hash = []
upc = @upc.dup
while whatover_condition_you_have
  final_hash.push({upc: upc.shift, vendor: @vendor, type: @type, color: @color})
end
```